# How do I convert Word files to PDF using Word 2007 programmatically?

Tags: pdf-generation, office-2007, word-automation

I used to convert Word documents to PDF via Word Automation: Enumerate the CommandBars until one containing "PDFmaker" was found, enumerating its controls and executing it.

With Word 2007 this no longer works - although the PdfMaker Com Addin is installed and accessible via the Acrobat menu.

PDFmaker is required for quality reasons. Therefore I cannot use the Microsoft "Save as PDF" addin; so the SaveAs method described in another post here is not applicable.

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to access the button as usual?

Comment: I get enumerated 176 CommandBar objects, none of them contains "PDFmaker"

Comment: Are you using `Recursive:=True` in `.FindControl`?

Answer (score 2):

A common way to get a PDF out of Word is to print to a virtual PDF printer. I could bet you have one installed. Maybe you find the quality appropriate.

The code would be:

```
Application.ActivePrinter = "whatever PDF printer you've got"
ThisDocument.PrintOut OutputFileName:="c:\whatever.pdf", PrintToFile:=True
```

Comment: This does not provide hyperlinks and bookmarks. As said before, PDFMaker is required.